# $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ continuous function such that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is convergent ; is $\{f(n)\}$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is convergent ; is $\{f(n)\}$  bounded  ?  I know that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then $\{f(n)\}$ converges to $0$ , but I don't know what happens under assumption of continuity of $f$ only . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example $f$ could be zero everywhere, except for having triangular spikes of height $n$ and width $n^{-3}$ centered around each $n$.

---

If you want your $f$ to be $\mathcal C^{\infty}$, replace the triangular spikes with scaled and squashed copies of a fixed [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

You can even make it real analytic:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-(n^3(x-n))^2} $$