# Is there a continuous function such that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges, yet $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x) \ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is there a continuous function such that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges, yet $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x) \ne 0$?

I know there are such functions, but I just can't think of any example.

Comment: Think of a function that is mostly zero but which has peaks at each $x = n$ enclosing areas of the size $1/n^2$.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$, see [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Comment: The examples so far are about integrable functions which do not have a (pointwise) limit as $x$ tends to infinity. It seems that in case $f(x)$ has a non-zero limit the integral does not exist.

Comment: @Urgje Indeed, if $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\ell\neq0$, then for all $0<\varepsilon<|\ell|/2$, there exists $M>0$ such that for all $x>M$ we have $|f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$, so that $|f(x)|>|\ell|-\varepsilon>|\ell|/2$, so $\int_{]M,+\infty[}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x>\int{_{]M,+\infty[}}|\ell|/2\mathrm{d}x= + infty $, and then $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $]0,+\infty[$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623364

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a picture (not very accurate, I know), to see how to construct a counter-example:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

The $n$-th triangle centered at $x=n$ have basis of length $1/n^2$.
This is Friedrich Philipp's idea.

Comment: If we want we can write the function as $$f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\chi_{[n-c_n,n]}\frac{(x-n+c_n)}{c_n} + \chi_{[n,n+c_n]}\frac{(n+c_n-x)}{c_n}$$ where $c_n = \frac{1}{n^2-1}$ and $\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. However I think this a good example of a situation where a picture is much better than an explicit formula.

Comment: I should have written "This is [Friedrich Philipp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/303983/friedrich-philipp)'s idea (in an above comment)", to be clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Let 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}n^2(x-n),&\ x\in[n,n+1/n^2], \\ -n^2x+n^3+2,&\ x\in[n+1/n^2,n+2/n^2]\\ 0,&\ x\in[n+2/n^2,n+1)
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous, $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$, and
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6.
$$
Note also that, by pushing this idea, we can get $f$ to be unbounded (by making the triangles thin quicker and get higher).

Comment: Nice one, I'm stupid

Comment: No, usually you have to see these things once, and then you remember the idea.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm afraid I don't understand your function definition. Is the $n$ fixed for $f$ to be solely a function of $x$? If it is then it seems that $f$ is only defined on a finite interval, which can't be right. I'm obviously missing something here so if you could explain in a bit more detail I'd be much obliged.

Comment: Why is $f$ continuous, it seems discontinuous at each $x=n$ - zero on the left and $n^3$ on the right ?

Comment: @Svetoslav:  Yes, there was a typo. It is corrected now.

Comment: @K.Power: given any $x\geq0$, there is a single integer $n $ with $x\in [n,n+1) $.